# ActionController::UnknownFormat in HomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

i am using angularjs in my rails application .
in my js file i have code like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('locationController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.user = {};
    $http.get('./locations.json').success((data) 
    $scope.locations = data
  )})
```

and in my controller action 
respond_to :json

```
def index  
  @locations  = Location.all
  respond_with(@locations)
end
```

Comment: in my routes.rb   resources :locations , :defaults => {:format => "json"}

Answer (score 0):

I just corrected some syntax errors please let me know once you check with these below corrections.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('locationController',function($scope,$http){

$scope.user = {};

$http.get('./locations.json').success(function(data) {
if(data)
$scope.locations = data;
});
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply ,i have corrected the syntax error but its showig locations.json not found

Comment: can you check the relative path for locations.json is correct or not ?